# information from observed values of random variables equivalent to knowing values of indicator functions of sets in generated sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I read the following statement in "David Williams: Probability with Martingales":

Let $\{Y_{\gamma},\gamma \in C\}$ be a collection of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$. The following information about the chosen point $\omega$ is equivalent:

(1) the values $Y_{\gamma}(\omega)$ of all the random variables

(2) the values $I_F(\omega)$ for all $F \in \mathscr{Y}$ where $\mathscr{Y}=\sigma(\{Y_{\gamma},\gamma \in C\})$ is the sigma algebra generated by all the random variables

I see that (2) implies (1). For any $b \in R$ knowing $I_{Y_{\gamma}^{-1}(b)}(\omega)$ we can tell whether $Y_{\gamma}=b$ or not. So we can tell the values of all $Y_{\gamma}$.

I would go about proving the converse as follows: It holds for a single random variable. Any $F \in \mathscr{Y}$ is of the form $Y^{-1}(B)$ for some Borel Set $B$. Given $I_F(\omega)=b$, we can deduce that $I_{Y^{-1}(B)}(\omega)$ is $1$ if $b=Y(\omega) \in B$ and $0$ otherwise.

For finitely many random variables $Y_1,...Y_n$, $A=\{Y_1^{-1}([- \infty,x_1]) \cap...\cap Y_n^{-1}([- \infty,x_n]),x_1,...,x_n \in [- \infty,\infty]\}$ is a $\pi$-system generating $\mathscr{Y}=\sigma(\{Y_{\gamma},1\leq \gamma \leq n\})$. From knowing (1) we can tell $I_F(\omega)$ for $F \in A$. Now $F \rightarrow I_F(\omega)$ is a measure on $\mathscr{Y}$, it is uniquely determined by knowing its values on the $\pi$-system $A$.

For countably many random variables, set $X_n=\sigma(Y_1,...Y_n)$ and $X_{\infty}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$. $X_{\infty}$ is a $\pi$-system generating  $\mathscr{Y}=\sigma(\{Y_{\gamma},\gamma \in C\})$ and knowing (1) we know $I_F(\omega)$ for $F$ in that $\pi$-system and thus on all of $\mathscr{Y}$.

First of all, can please someone confirm that my argument is correct. Is there maybe another, easier proof? Secondly, the statement doesn't make any assumption about countability. Is the statement true for uncountably many random variables and how can it be proven?